# How do I create KeyEvents in Java FXML?

Tags: javafx, fxml, onkeypress, key-events

I created this small project to test key events. But when I press keys, it isn't behaving as I want. Actually I need key events for my Calculator project. I created a Calculator project and aside from mouse clicks, I want to add a feature where numbers or operators can be typed from a keyboard. Can anyone check this and help make it more functional?

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable{

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private Button backSpace;

@FXML
private Button spaceBar;

@FXML
private Button enter;

@FXML
void typedBS(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
        label.setText(event.getText() + " typed.");
    }
}

@FXML
void typedE(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode()==KeyCode.ENTER) {
        label.setText(event.getText() + " typed");
    }
}

@FXML
void typedSB(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode()==KeyCode.SPACE) {
        label.setText(event.getText()+" typed");
    }
}

@FXML
void PressBackSpace(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
        label.setText("You pressed Back Space key!");
    }
}

@FXML
void clickBackSpace(ActionEvent event) {
    label.setText("You clicked Back Space key!");
}

@FXML
void clickEnter(ActionEvent event) {
    label.setText("You clicked Enter key!");
}

@FXML
void clickSpaceBar(ActionEvent event) {
    label.setText("You clicked SpaceBar key!");
}

@FXML
void pressEnter(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        label.setText("You pressed Enter key!");
    }
}

@FXML
void pressSpaceBar(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
        label.setText("You pressed SpaceBar key!");
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using SceneBuilder?

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions?

Comment: What is your root node?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Scene Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you look at this FXML file you can see my root node(The AnchorPane) has an onKeyPressed and onKeyReleased.

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" onKeyPressed="#handleOnKeyPressed" onKeyReleased="#handleOnKeyReleased" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="855.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="atmfx.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <BorderPane layoutX="263.0" layoutY="94.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <left>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="apLeftDisplay" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
```

> In The Controller my method that handles these two KeyEvents are

```
@FXML
private void handleOnKeyReleased(KeyEvent event)
{
    System.out.println();
    Button tempButton = buttons.get(event.getText());
    System.out.println("Released key text: " + event.getText());
    System.out.println("Released key code: " + event.getCode());

    if (tempButton != null) {
        tempButton.disarm();
        tempButton.setStyle("");
    }
    else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
        tempButton = buttons.get("enter");
        tempButton.disarm();
        tempButton.setStyle("");
    }
    else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)) {
        tempButton = buttons.get("backspace");
        tempButton.disarm();
        tempButton.setStyle("");
    }
    else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)) {
        tempButton = buttons.get("space");
        tempButton.disarm();
        tempButton.setStyle("");
    }
}

@FXML
private void handleOnKeyPressed(KeyEvent event)
{
    Button tempButton = buttons.get(event.getText());
    System.out.println("Pressed key text: " + event.getText());
    System.out.println("Pressed key code: " + event.getCode());
    if (tempButton != null) {
        tempButton.arm();
        tempButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
    }
    else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
        tempButton = buttons.get("enter");
        tempButton.arm();
        tempButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
    }
    else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)) {
        tempButton = buttons.get("backspace");
        tempButton.arm();
        tempButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
    }
    else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)) {
        tempButton = buttons.get("space");
        tempButton.arm();
        tempButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
    }
}
```

> In this code I added all of my buttons to a HasMap. That way in my keyevent handlers I was able to retrieve the button depending on the keyboard key I pressed.

```
Map<String, Button> buttons = new HashMap<>();
TheButtonsParentNode.getChildren().stream().filter((tempNode)
            -> (tempNode instanceof Button)).map((
            tempNode) -> (Button) tempNode).forEachOrdered((tempButton) -> {
        buttons.put(tempButton.getText().toLowerCase(), tempButton);//adding button text and the button to hashmap
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the event and the handling in the same thing.
try something like this:
if u are using a borderpane as an example

```
borderPane.setOnKeyPressed(this::handleKeyPress);

private void handleKeyPress(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
        label.setText(event.getText() + " typed.");
    }
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE) {
        label.setText("You pressed SpaceBar key!");
    }
     //TODO
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Gordon, thank you for your answer. What I meant is that I want to use these in Java FXML Application. In JavaFX it is working... I'm trying to master Java FXML as well, so if you can, please show some code regarding this issue by doing it in Java FXML project. In my answer I posted the code of my Controller class.